# Inserindo dados usando JPA

Tags: java, primefaces, jpa

Preciso de um auxílio para salvar os dados de uma aplicação usando JPA. 
Segui um tutorial que só auxiliava na implementação do login mas não mostrou como salvar os dados. No caso, estou tentando cadastrar um usuário. 
Quando eu clico em salvar mostra uma mensagem de erro que acredito ser por falta de alguma implementação:

```
 javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /cadUsuario.xhtml @22,136 value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.usuario}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'UsuarioMB' resolved to null
```

Classe Usuário

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIOS")
//@NamedQuery(name="query", query="SELECT c FROM Cliente c")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "USUARIO", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private String usuario;

    @Column(name = "SENHA", length = 5, nullable = false)
    private String senha;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

Classe UsuarioDAO

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import model.Usuario;

public class UsuarioDAO {

    private EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("usuarios");
    private EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    public Usuario getUsuario(String usuario, String senha) {

        try {
            Usuario usu = (Usuario) em
                    .createQuery(
                            "SELECT u from Usuario u where u.usuario = :usuario and u.senha = :senha")
                    .setParameter("usuario", usuario)
                    .setParameter("senha", senha).getSingleResult();

            return usu;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean inserirUsuario(Usuario usuario) { 

        try {         
            em.persist(usuario);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean deletarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        try {
            em.remove(usuario);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Classe UsuarioMB

```
import daos.UsuarioDAO;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import model.Usuario;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioMB {

    private Usuario usuario;

    public UsuarioMB() {

    }



    public UsuarioMB(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

}
```

pagina de cadastro no caso

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
        <title>Lavagem Godoi</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    </h:head>
    <ui:include src="menu/menu.xhtml" />
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="msgs"/>
            <p:messages id="messages" />
            <p:fieldset legend="Cadastro de Usuário" style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputLabel for="id" value="Id"  />
                    <p:inputText id="id" value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.id}" disabled="true" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="usuario" value="Nome do Usuário:" />
                    <p:inputText id="usuario" value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.usuario}" required="true" requiredMessage="Insira o usuário"/>

                    <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha:" />
                    <p:password id="senha" value="#{UsuarioMB.usuario.senha}" required="true" requiredMessage="Insira a senha"/>

                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{UsuarioDAO.inserirUsuario}" > </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por parte amigo. Veja que o action do botão salvar ou inserir no caso chama um método do Dao e não do Bean. O jsf não conhece seu Dao então você não pode fazer referência a ele ao menos que ele esteja com a anotação de Bean o que não é o caso.
O que te aconselho a fazer é criar um método inserir no seu bean e então chamar o método inserir do dao dentro dele.
Exemplo:

```
public void inserir(){
dao.inserir(usuario)
}
```

Este erro não está relacionado ao JPA e sim ao valor da sua propriedade que está nulla. Crie um método inicial no seu ManagedBean com a anotação @PostConstruct, e inicie sua propriedade, por exemplo:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
  usuario = new Usuario();
}
```

e dê um nome para seu managedBean exemplo:

```
ManagedBean(name = "UsuarioMB")
```

Comment: Sua solução resolveu esse problema. Entretanto apareceu outro que deve questionada em outra pergunta. De qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke você viu a minha resposta?

Comment: sim..essa questão eu consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0):

> `Target Unreachable, identifier 'UsuarioMB' resolved to null`

No xhtml, mais especificamente na EL, você deve referenciar seu ManagedBean com letra minúscula.

Você está fazendo assim:

```
#{UsuarioMB.usuario.usuario}
```

Deve ser feito assim:

```
#{usuarioMB.usuario.usuario}
```

---

O ManagedBean está sendo referenciado diversas vezes com letra maiúscula.

Altere todas ocorrências para minúsculo.

Comment: Se o usuário deu um nome para o bean, e esse foi com letra minúscula então ele pode ser referenciado com letra minúscula.